# How to make post call in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to post a data controller, but I can't get any data back. In ordinary method I use .ajax method to post or get methods. I tried this code but cannot post to controller:

```
$scope.LoadProductDetails = function () {
    $http.post('/Home/sample/', $scope.contacts).success(function (data) {
        if (data.Result == "OK") {
            var a = data.Data;
            $scope.cont.push(a);
            angular.forEach($scope.cont, function (todo) {
                $scope.datalist.push(todo);
            });
            alert("Message Posted Successfully...");
        }
    });
};
```

Here $scope.contacts:

```
$scope.contacts = [
    {
        id: 0,
        'name': 'Viral',
        'email': 'hello@gmail.com',
        'phone': '123-2344'
    },
    {
        id: 01,
        'name': 'Vira',
        'email': 'hlo@gmil.com',
        'phone': '123-2343-44'
    },
    ...
];
```

Any on help to improve this one?

Comment: Errors? And show `$scope.contacts` structure.

Comment: $scope.contacts = [
        { id:0, 'name': 'Viral', 
          'email':'hello@gmail.com', 
          'phone': '123-2344'
        },{ id:01, 'name': 'Vira', 
          'email':'hlo@gmil.com', 
          'phone': '123-2343-44'
        },{ id:02, 'name': 'Vir', 
          'email':'heo@gmail.com', 
          'phone': '123--44'
        },{ id:03, 'name': 'Vi', 
          'email':'llo@gmail.com', 
          'phone': '123--44'
        },{ id:04, 'name': 'V', 
          'email':'he@gmail.com', 
          'phone': '123-2344'
        }
    ];

Comment: Your method looks okay. Could you show me your controller?

Comment: public JsonResult sample(List<sample> data1)
        {
            string Message = "ERR";
            if (data1 != null&&data1.Count>0)
            {
                foreach(var a in data1)
                {
                    a.name = "sankar";
                    a.phone = 555454;
                    a.email = "khskjhjsa";
                }
            Message = "OK";
            }
            return Json(new { Result = Message, Data = data1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: @Sankar You **do** have an option to **edit your question** in order to provide updates, instead of overflowing the comments with extensive code.

Comment: Have you used FromBody attribute for input method of your action in controller? Any way if you put your Action in controller you can get your answer faster